# get "conflicting types error" in JNI with C

Tags: c++, c, types, java-native-interface

I try to compiled this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include "callJNITest.h"

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_callJNITest_displayHelloWorld
  (JNIEnv env, jclass jcls) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return 1;
}
```

But I always get these errors:
../HelloWorldJNI.c:5:24: error: conflicting types for ‘Java_callJNITest_displayHelloWorld’
../callJNITest.h:15:24: note: previous declaration of ‘Java_callJNITest_displayHelloWorld’ was here
make: *** [HelloWorldJNI.o] Error 1

The error happened also in this case:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_callJNITest_displayHelloWorld
  (JNIEnv env, jclass jcls) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return;
}
```

but

```
JNIEXPORT JNICALL Java_callJNITest_displayHelloWorld
  (JNIEnv env, jclass jcls) {
    printf("Hello World!");
    return;
}
```

works fine.
My question is how return types should be declared in JNI? Thanks!

Comment: What's in callJNITest.h?

Comment: /* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
    #include <jni.h>
    #ifndef _Included_callJNITest
    #define _Included_callJNITest
    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif
    JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_callJNITest_displayHelloWorld
    (JNIEnv *, jclass);

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif
    #endif

Comment: Looks like you use JNIEnv for env in the cpp file when it should be JNIEnv*

Answer (score 1):

Creating an answer from my comment since it solved the OP's problem.

The header file contains a declaration where the type of the first argument of `Java_callJNITest_displayHelloWorld`is a `JNIEnv*`, while in the cpp file it has the type `JNIEnv`. 
The fix is to change the type of `env` in the cpp file to `JNIEnv*` so that it matches the declaration in the header file.